# How to repair a broken compiler?

Tags: compiling, gcc

Few months ago I was using **gcc 4.6.** In order to get C++11 functionality I upgraded to **gcc 4.7** using a **PPA**. Today gcc 4.7 was recommended to me through **the update manager**. I just mindlessly clicked "Install all available updates".

Now when I try to build my project in C++, I get the following error:

[image]

The first thing that came to my mind was to uninstall gcc and install it again through the **Synaptic Package Manager**.

But something tells me that things *may not be as straightforward as it seems*. Compiler is an essential part of the OS and I am afraid I can lose the capacity to install anything. I remember that when I was upgrading to gcc 4.7 from gcc 4.6 things were also not so trivial.

Please, where can I find more information on the subject? Is it ok to just reinstall the gcc using Synaptic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian packages (`.deb`, used also by Ubuntu) are packages consisting of compiled binaries (unless you want the source code package). This means that during installation, there is no need for a compiler - the necessary files are already compiled, they are just unpacked.

It *should* be safe to `purge` the offending `gcc` and install the version from the main repository, but there is no guarantee it will work without problems.

To help you get rid of the PPA from which you installed `gcc4.7`, take a look at [PPA-Purge](http://hackedbellini.org/applications/ppa-purge-the-best-friend-for-people-who-lives-on-bleeding-edge/), which helps you with cleaning custom PPAs - it will automatically downgrade all packages to official version and remove the PPA from the system.